# Hadoop Ecosystem - What technological tool combination to use in my scenrio? (Details Inside)

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive, apache-pig, mahout

This might be an interesting question to some:

**Given:** 2-3 Terabyte of data stored in **SQL Server**(RDBMS), consider it similar to Amazons data, i.e., users -> what things they saw/clicked to see -> what they bought

**Task:** Make a recommendation engine (like Amazon), which displays to user, customer who bought this also bought this -> if you liked this, then you might like this -> (Also) kind of data mining to predict future buying habits as well(Data Mining). So on and so forth, basically a reco engine.

**Issue:** Because of the sheer volume of data (5-6 yrs worth of user habit data), I see Hadoop as the ultimate solution. Now the question is, what technological tools combinations to use?, i.e.,

> HDFS: Underlying FIle system
>
> HBASE/HIVE/PIG: ?
>
> Mahout: For running some algorithms, which I assume uses Map-Reduce (genetic, cluster, data mining etc.)
>
> **- What am I missing? What about loading RDBMS data for all this processing? (*Sqoop for Hadoop?*)**
>
> **- At the end of all this, I get a list of results(reco's), or there exists a way to query it directly and report it to the front-end I build in .NET??**

I think the answer to this question, just might be a good discussion for many people like me in the future who want to kick start their hadoop experimentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For loading data from RDBMS, I'd recommend looking into BCP (to export from SQL to flat file) then Hadoop command line for loading into HDFS.  Sqoop is good for ongoing data but it's going to be intolerably slow for your initial load.

To query results from Hadoop you can use HBase (assuming you want low-latency queries), which can be queried from C# via it's Thrift API.

Comment: so you're suggesting that in my case, I don't need Sqoop, and might not need Pig/Hive as well? 
Also, what about ruuning some algorithms? Mahout?

Comment: Pig and Hive are useful for running exploratory work.  We don't use them for production jobs because hand-written MapReduce is often orders of magnitude faster.  You probably want to look into Cascading for writing your MR jobs- http://www.cascading.org/.  Oozie has it's place, but like any tool that uses ODBC/JDBC its going to be several orders of magnitude slower than bulk copying data for your initial data load.

Comment: thanks for the inputs buddy. I'm looking into your suggestions right now..and am leaving this question as open for now since I want other people to participate as well! :-)
I'd welcome all your other additional comments.

Comment: Ack- by oozie in the comment above I meant sqoop.  Oozie is a workflow manager for Hadoop jobs.  Also quite good but very quirky.

Answer (score 0):

HBase can fit your scenario.
HDFS is the underlying file system. Nevertheless you cannot load the data in HDFS (in arbitrary format) query in HBase, unless you use the HBase file format (HFile)

HBase has integration with MR. 
Pig and Hive also integrate with HBase. 
As Chris mentioned it, you can use Thrift to perform your queries (get, scan) since this will extract specific user info and not a massive data set it is more suitable than using MR.

Comment: thanks for replying. I understand that HBase fits my needs as its not an active query/result generating model Im going for. A question here is, for running any algorithms for recommendation, trend analysis, predictive modelling - what do you suggest? Mahout? Cascading (as suggested by @Chris Shain) to write Map-Reduce jobs or something else?!

Comment: MR either via pig or Hive, for fast prototyping, then move to coded MR